# Jquery Ui autocomplete is not loadin data from http://ws.geonames.org/

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

[Visit my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQFJ7/)

The data  from http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=DE is not loading, and if I change that into http://www.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=DE it says I need a username.

Here is jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(".city").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=DE",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term,
            countryName: "Germany"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                    value: item.name
                }
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

});

Is there any alternative to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You should use `http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=DE` instead of `http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=DE`
The latter is for premium web service so you need an account
Second:`http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=DE&country=DE&lang=en&username=demo&callback=?`
You can use demo but it has a hourly limit of 2000 queries (shared by a lot of people), you can create a free account but it has limited credits too. Not sure how much visits you are expecting per day.